# How can I insert/upload files to a specific folder in Google Drive API v3 using Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Everyday I download many pdf files which are stored onto my local PC.  To store all of them, I need to create a folder onto Google drive daily basis and store all the pdf files under the current date folder.
My challenge over here is I have successfully completed coding in Python to create folder using GDrive API v3 but stuck in uploading all the files onto the folder just created.  Below is my coding how I achieved to create folder by current date:

```
    import pickle
    import os.path, time
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
    from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
    from datetime import date
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'e:\\Python Programs\\credentials.json'

    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
      with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
      if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
      else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
      pickle.dump(creds, token)

    # main folder ID under which we are going to create subfolder
    parents_ID = '19nKlHGCypKPr40f3vjaEq22kgVkS7OCE'
    # creates sub folder under main folder ID
    fldr_name = date.today().strftime('%d%b%Y')
    mimetype = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    file_metadata = {'name': fldr_name, 'parents': [parents_ID],'mimeType': mimetype}
    # with following line I could successfully create folder without any problem
    service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()

    # with following lines, i tried to get the folder ID which was recently created so that I can start coding to upload pdf files onto this.  Here im stuck
    page_token = None
    response =  service.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = '27Apr2020' and trashed = false", spaces='drive', fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)', pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
      print(file.get('name'), file.get('id'))
    time.sleep(5)
```

I am getting blank screen for 5 sec then it gets vanished.  Please help me to upload all my files to my recently created folder.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in Googles documentation? The only modifications you would need to do is loop over the pdfs in your local dir and process them. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder

Comment: have you been successful in creating the `drive_service()` ? In other words, did you get an access token from the API, and did you allow the scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"? You app needs access to that scope to upload files to Drive. Please share the rest of the code you have tried, and **remove sentsitive info before posting**

Comment: H Aerials.. thanks for your response.  Yes i have edited my question with full code.  and ofcourse  I have set my scope googleapis.com/auth/drive.file only.  I succeeded creating sub-folder under one prime folder. Prob is immediately after I created I want to upload many pdf files onto the subfolder which is created through coding.  So I need to know the folder ID to proceed further in the same program.

Comment: I found answer.  Thanks all

Comment: Great @Salomon you can post your solution? or what helped you get there?

Answer (score 1):

From your above Code, the following line already returns the id of the folder just created(fields='id').

```
service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()
```

you can also return other values (name, parents, etc.) using the fields parameter while creating the folder,

```
service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id, name, parents').execute()
```

so if you catch the return value in a variable like below,

```
folder = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()
```

the returned value looks like {'id': '17w2RS1H7S8no6X0oGtkieY'}

you can then upload file by the commands below.

```
file_metadata = {
        'name': "test.pdf", <Name of the file to be in drive>
        'parents': [folder["id"]],
        'mimeType': 'application/pdf'
    }
media = MediaFileUpload(<local path to file>, resumable=True)
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id,name').execute()
```

you need to import the following,

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
```